# onChange Script keeps returning to certain SpreadSheet - Google pps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Every time I make edits to any of the 5 other spreadsheets, as soon as I finish editing a cell, I am returned to sheet name "HOLDING". I would like this to stop happening.

```
function onChange(e) {

 DeleteRow(e);
}
function DeleteRow(e) {
// This Code will delete any "Y" in Column E.

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('HOLDING'), true);
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();
var rowsDeleted = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if (row[4] == "Y") {
sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
rowsDeleted++;
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to [`setActiveSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#setactivesheetsheet,-restoreselection) is what's causing the active sheet to change.

Try replacing the first couple lines of `DeleteRow()` with an approach that will allow you to interact with the `HOLDING` sheet without making it active:

```
function DeleteRow(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('HOLDING');

  <...continue with the rest of the original implementation...>
```